# Reading DBF file in pandas and save as DF

Tags: python, pandas, dbf

I have a file (screen) in DBF format. I want to write it to the data frame. I found a post: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41898561/pandas-transform-a-dbf-table-into-a-dataframe`

And I do what I want with geopandas. But the problem is, that geopandas it's a problematic library. I transfer my code to friend, and he can't run script coz dependencies were broken (I have read that's a common problem with geopandas). So I tried to use another method from the post:

```
from simpledbf import Dbf5
dbf = Dbf5('K01.dbf')
```

But in this case, I got a coding error: `'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xae in position 10: invalid start byte`. It's possible to handle it?

File: [image: screenshot 1]

File opened in excel:[image: screenshot 2]

I need to read it and put in pandas data frame. Can anyone help with it?

Comment: Look here: https://gist.github.com/celisflen-bers/fe827aa724997b0487a084d225054e2c and try to convert the dbf to csv. If it works - you can use panadas read_csv

Comment: `File "<ipython-input-23-1d16aa3c953b>", line 2, in <module>
    from dbfpy import dbf

  File "C:\...\dbf.py", line 280
    print repr(_rec)`  So something is wrong in python3 :(

Comment: Do you have one dbf file only or multiple files? If it is one (or few files only), you can following https://smallbusiness.chron.com/convert-dbf-xls-55554.html and after that use pandas.